# Search a pattern with less without losing the current one?

Tags: less

I use `/` for search. Once I press enter I use `n` and `N` to navigate. If I press `/` again though the old pattern is lost. 90% of the times I want to append the pattern and I have to retype, which I naturally hate it. Is there an option to append the current pattern in less?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`less` remembers previous searches (even from previous executions, if you have a history file — `~/.lesshst` by default). To access them, press <kbd>/</kbd> and the arrow keys. For your specific use-case, you’d press <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd>, `less` will show the previous pattern with the cursor at the end of the pattern, and you can type the additional pattern.

Comment: So simple and yet, it didn't cross my mind... Thanks. (8 minutes to go)